# How can i save a people/group picker from infopath to Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, people-picker

i'm start to learn infopath and code, so i don't know how to do this:

i need to save a user for a form infopath to sharepoint i only know this:

root.SelectSingleNode("/my:misCampos/my:grupo15/my:cliente/pc:Person/pc:AccountId", NamespaceManager).Value;

how can i save?

Answer (score 2):

Jose,

[Creating People Picker Form in InfoPath 2010](http://www.edutechnow.com/?p=446) and [How to map person/group picker](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23151/82402.aspx) should help

Comment: thxs, but i try to do by code, actually i do this:

Comment: 1.- XPathNavigator root = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
2.- string tipoProyecto = root.SelectSingleNode("/my:misCampos/my:tipoProyecto", NamespaceManager).Value;
3.- oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
4.- SPList list = oWeb.Lists["LTMDP01 DATOS PROYECTO"];
5.- SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
6.- item["Tipo Proyecto"] = tipoProyecto.ToString();
but i can do (2 and 6) to a user picker